# How to make Unordered List dragable with multiple rows

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

How to make Unordered List dragable with multiple rows as below (using ul-li)

Below code is for splitting listitems into rows....how that can be dragable and sortable

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        debugger;
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var size = 5,//Change number for the rows you want to display
          $ul = $("ul"),
          $lis = $ul.children().filter(':gt(' + (size - 1) + ')'),
          loop = Math.ceil($lis.length / size),
          i = 0;

            $ul.css('float', 'left').wrap("<div style='overflow: hidden'></div>");

            for (; i < loop; i = i + 1) {
                $ul = $("<ul />").css('float', 'left').append($lis.slice(i * size, (i * size) + 5)).insertAfter($ul); ////Change number for the rows you want to display
            }
        });

    </script>

<div>
     <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Above code is for splitting listitems into rows....how that can be dragable and sortable

Comment: jquery ui + css multi-column (IE10+)

Comment: I had included code can you please check the code & how can i implement drag and drop + sorting functionality on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you have included that much js code for sorting.
All you need to do is assign some id/class to the list and tag it to sortable function.

Please check below for the modified code:

Modified code:

> $(function() {
>
> $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
>
> $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
>
> });

check the below js fiddle link for live example:

jsfiddle.net/mxMKs/

Comment: I had included code for splitting ul to horizontal rows....i am able to sort and dragdrop in verticle direction but in horizontal its have ome issues....Check my comments in http://jsfiddle.net/mxMKs/1/  with your code and my code

Comment: i have modified the code to make it sortable in vertical and horizontal that is like grid check the modified fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mxMKs/2/)

Comment: Thanks Mahesh for your valueble time

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQueryUI sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) framework.

Refer to the above link, you will find a live demo using lists there.

Comment: Its not working for my requirement....thx

Comment: I had included code can you please check the code